# Accessing the query results within a Nova lens

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Currently using Nova v4 and creating a lens that I want to include a card on.

I don't see any way to actually access the query results that the lens is generating so that I can use them in my card.

I'm trying to use this Nova ChartJS package to show the results of a lens:
https://coroo.github.io/nova-chartjs

However, it seems to only allow adding a model reference or statically adding the values according to the examples in the docs, which is completely useless in with generated data.

Example from the docs:

```
    public function cards(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            (new StackedChart())
                ->title('Revenue')
                ->series([
                    [
                        'barPercentage'   => 0.5,
                        'label'           => 'Product #1',
                        'backgroundColor' => '#ffcc5c',
                        'data'            => [30, 70, 80],
                    ],
                ])
                ->options([
                    'xaxis' => [
                        'categories' => ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
                    ],
                ]),
        ];
    }
```

It would be fine if I could iterate thru a collection of the results of the lens to generate the data for the series, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the underlying data shown by the lens within the card method.

How it would actually be useful so I can work with the actual data in the chart:

```
    public function cards(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            (new StackedChart())
                ->title('Revenue')
                ->series($this->query()->get()->map(function ($record) {
                    return [
                        'barPercentage'   => 0.5,
                        'label'           => $record->name,
                        'backgroundColor' => $record->color,
                        'data'            => $record->data,
                    ] ;})->toArray())
                ->options([
                    'xaxis' => [
                        'categories' => $this->query()->get()->map(function ($record) {
                              return $record->created_at->day;
                    })->values()->toArray(),
                    ],
                ]),
        ];
    }
```

How do I actually use real in-context data within a card?

Comment: From my understanding and based on what the documentation says, you cannot mix Lenses with Cards, could you show us what you are trying to do (code)?

Comment: Updated with more context. There is a `cards()` method on the lens, so I would expect you can add cards to a lens.